# Openlayers 3 equivalent of Openlayers 2 OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP.options.params?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

Is there a way to send data to the server with POST request instead of GET ?

I used to use Protocol.HTTP.options.params for this purpose, but I can't find any equivalent in Openlayers 3 OpenLayers.source.Vector.

Comment: Same problem. Anybody?